# Java Using SimpleDateFormat to compare dates

Tags: java

Now I am doing a small project. And this project includes the compare among several dates.
So I convert "yyyy-MM-dd" to millisecond by using SimpleDateFormat.
However, it did not work out.
By the way, when I use more easy way, that is, compare year, month and day one by one, it works out! So the problem is about the SimpleDateFormat.

Here are the code:

```
    package GenericsPractice;

public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private MyDate birthday;

    public Employee(String name, int age, MyDate birthday) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public MyDate getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public void setBirthday(MyDate birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                ", birthday=" + birthday.toString();
    }

}
```

```
    package GenericsPractice;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class MyDate {
    private int month;
    private int day;
    private int year;

    public MyDate(int month, int day, int year) {
        this.month = month;
        this.day = day;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public void setMonth(int month) {
        this.month = month;
    }

    public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public void setDay(int day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public long dateToMills() throws ParseException {
        String date = (getYear())+"-"+(getMonth())+"-"+(getDay());
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        long time = sdf.parse(date).getTime();
        return time;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "month=" + month +
                ", day=" + day +
                ", year=" + year +
                '}';
    }
}
```

```
    import GenericsPractice.Employee;
import GenericsPractice.MyDate;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class EmployeeTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
//        TreeSet<Employee> set = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<Employee>() {
//            @Override
//            public int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2) {
//                int year = o1.getBirthday().getYear() - o2.getBirthday().getYear();
//                int month = o1.getBirthday().getMonth() - o2.getBirthday().getMonth();
//                int day = o1.getBirthday().getDay() - o2.getBirthday().getDay();
//                if(year != 0){
//                    return year;
//                }
//                if(month != 0){
//                    return month;
//                }
//                if(day != 0){
//                    return day;
//                }
//                return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
//            }
//        });

        TreeSet<Employee> set = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<Employee>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2) {
                try {
                    return (int)(o1.getBirthday().dateToMills()-o2.getBirthday().dateToMills());
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                throw new RuntimeException("输入类型不一致");
            }
        });

        set.add(new Employee("Chandler",23,new MyDate(10,18,1997)));
        set.add(new Employee("Ross",25,new MyDate(10,18,1992)));
        set.add(new Employee("Joey",20,new MyDate(3,15,1999)));
        set.add(new Employee("Monica",35,new MyDate(12,31,1990)));
        set.add(new Employee("Rachel",21,new MyDate(6,2,1998)));



        Iterator<Employee> iterator = set.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            Employee obj = iterator.next();
            System.out.println(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

When running, it did not sort by date:

```
Employee{name='Chandler', age=23, birthday=month=10, day=18, year=1997}
Employee{name='Monica', age=35, birthday=month=12, day=31, year=1990}
Employee{name='Ross', age=25, birthday=month=10, day=18, year=1992}  
Employee{name='Joey', age=20, birthday=month=3, day=15, year=1999}
Employee{name='Rachel', age=21, birthday=month=6, day=2, year=1998}
```

Comment: Describe _"did not work"_ in terms that anyone reading knows _exactly_ what is happening, such as input / output / expected behavior / actual behavior.

Comment: Is this for a school assignment? If so, say so. Different answers are appropriate if this is for real work versus school work.

Answer (score 2):

You said:

> So I convert "yyyy-MM-dd" to millisecond by using SimpleDateFormat

No, do not represent a date as a count of milliseconds. And, No, never use `SimpleDateFormat`. These terrible date-time classes were supplanted years ago. Use only the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Your code:

> `private int age;`

No, do not store age. You can dynamically calculate an age by comparing their date of birth to the current date.

Also, you need a time zone to calculate age. For any given moment, the current date varies around the globe by time zone. It is "tomorrow" in Tokyo Japan while simultaneously "yesterday" in Toledo Ohio US.

Your code:

> class MyDate

No, do not invent your own class to represent a date. We have the [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) class for that.

Note that `LocalDate` implements [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html). So `LocalDate` objects know how to compare and sort amongst themselves. This behavior will be useful in code seen below.

To simplify your class definition, let's make it a `record`. [Records are a new feature in Java 16](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395), for a class whose main purpose is transparently and immutably carrying data. The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, the getters, `hashCode` & `equals`, and `toString`. You could just as well define a conventional class.

```java
package org.example;

import java.time.LocalDate;

public record Person( String name , LocalDate dateOfBirth )
{
}
```

If you want an age-calculator as mentioned above, add a `age` method.

```java
package org.example;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;
import java.time.ZoneId;

public record Person(String name , LocalDate dateOfBirth)
{
    public int age ( ZoneId zoneId ) { return Period.between( this.dateOfBirth , LocalDate.now( zoneId ) ).getYears(); }
}
```

In real work, I would add an explicit constructor that used `Objects.requireNonNull` to ensure no `null` arguments were received. Ditto for `age` method, verify `ZoneId` argument is not null.

For specifying our input objects, let's use `Set.of` syntax. Then later feed the resulting unmodifiable `Set` object to our `TreeSet`.

```java
Set < Person > peopleInput =
        Set.of(
                new Person( "Chandler" , LocalDate.of( 1997 , 10 , 18 ) ) ,
                new Person( "Ross" , LocalDate.of( 1992 , 10 , 18 ) ) ,
                new Person( "Joey" , LocalDate.of( 1999 , 3 , 15 ) ) ,
                new Person( "Monica" , LocalDate.of( 1990 , 12 , 31 ) ) ,
                new Person( "Rachel" , LocalDate.of( 1998 , 6 , 2 ) )
        );
```

Much easier nowadays to use lambda/streams syntax for specifying a `Comparator`. You could write a conventional comparator as seen in your Question, but doing so is more likely to be incorrect, and less readable.

As discussed in [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65987719/642706) to [your similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65986838/642706) yesterday, the `Comparator`/`Comparable` implementation used in your `NavigableSet` must be *consistent with `equals`*. If two objects being compared are named `a` and `b`, then “consistent with equals” means that where `a.equals(b)` returns `true`, so must `a.compareTo(b) == 0` return `true`. So we must include both member fields `name` & `dateOfBirth` as those fields are used in our record’s default implementation of `equals`.

```java
Comparator < Person > comparingByDateOfBirthAndThenName =
        Comparator
                .comparing( Person :: dateOfBirth )
                .thenComparing( Person :: name );
```

Construct our `TreeSet` using that `Comparator` object.

```java
NavigableSet < Person > people = new TreeSet <>( comparingByDateOfBirthAndThenName );
```

Populate with the objects we instantiated via `Set.of`. As the objects are added, the `TreeSet`, being a `NavigableSet`, uses our `Comparator` object to sort them.

```java
people.addAll( peopleInput );
```

Dump to console.

```java
System.out.println( "peopleInput = " + peopleInput );
System.out.println( "people = " + people );
```

When run.

```
peopleInput = [Person[name=Chandler, dateOfBirth=1997-10-18], Person[name=Rachel, dateOfBirth=1998-06-02], Person[name=Joey, dateOfBirth=1999-03-15], Person[name=Ross, dateOfBirth=1992-10-18], Person[name=Monica, dateOfBirth=1990-12-31]]
people = [Person[name=Monica, dateOfBirth=1990-12-31], Person[name=Ross, dateOfBirth=1992-10-18], Person[name=Chandler, dateOfBirth=1997-10-18], Person[name=Rachel, dateOfBirth=1998-06-02], Person[name=Joey, dateOfBirth=1999-03-15]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for correction! I am new to Java, and your advice mean a lot to me! I will keep up learning!